# Map results from dynamic pivot proc to a class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pivot-table

I'm trying to figure out how to receive data from my stored procedure when its a pivot and has dynamic no of columns in its result set. The final collection I use to create a graph for year on year totals from Jan - Dec. I've no idea how to work around the idea that the class needs to be defined up front. Anyone, thanks in advance..

```
public class rptQuoteSwitchChart
{
    [StringLength(3)]
    public string Month { get; set; }
    public int s2015 { get; set; } // This column is dynamic (source is a pivot statement)
    public int s2016 { get; set; } // This column is dynamic (source is a pivot statement)
}

public ICollection<rptQuoteSwitchChart> RunStoredProcedureQuoteSwitchChart()
{

    ICollection<rptQuoteSwitchChart> result = new List<rptQuoteSwitchChart>();

    try
    {


        result = _db.Database.SqlQuery<rptQuoteSwitchChart>("EXEC dbo.GetQuotationsHistory").ToList();
        return result;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        writeToErrorLog(ex.InnerException.ToString(), ex.Message, "H");
        return result;


    }

}
```

Comment: Hi John, I would like to help you. There are few things which I might need to know prior, The way you are getting the pivot data result from the SP (So we can think of a clean generic method to model our classs), What format of data should you give to the graph (as there are 1000's of plugin's we dev's can use)

Comment: I get the data back from the PROC with the line 

  result = _db.Database.SqlQuery<rptQuoteSwitchChart>("EXEC dbo.GetQuotationsHistory").ToList();
      
Once I have that collection I build a string and JQUERY builds the graph which is google charts

Comment: I the class could somehow be dynamic, I Would be fine from there

Comment: Perhaps an array would sort this i'm thinking

Comment: You need to get the data into a dataset and then do a loop for each row in the dataset and add all the columns to List<string> Columns {get;set;} and the First row into List<string> Row{get;set;}. You will have one object with these two properties (Columns and Row) as mentioned above.. And create such one object for each row. Say you get back 40 rows from DB you need to construct 40 objects each one having List of columns and respective row data. This way you have modeled a generic object which you can pass to the view and play in jquery.